# android - using byte[] after taking picture in the app itself

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I take picture and wanna put it in the ImageView in another Activity but something goes wrong. Here is my code:

```
Camera mCamera;

//Some Code

public void onClick(View v) {
    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);        
}

Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {           
    }
};

Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;

        Intent inCapture = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        //Actually, I don't know where to put it: here or in jpegCallback
        inCapture.putExtra("captured", data);
        startActivity(inCapture);
    }
};

Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        //My attempt to load the result into ImageView in the same Activity - didn't work too
        if (data != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    data);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(imageStream);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(
                    getResources(), theImage));
        }
    }
};
```

It's not running SecondActivity and I don't know how to state my intent in onClick() and be able to put byte[] data in it (different classes and I can't make intent static - at least, I couldn't). Is there a better way to capture photo and pass that very byte[] to the other Activity?

P.S. I know there is also Camera2 that is newer but so far I did't get the point how to use it.

Comment: The "better way" is not to use separate activities. You cannot readily pass a photo to another activity, because it is too large for an `Intent` extra. Use one activity and separate fragments instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare then how to put my bitmap in the imageView in the same Activity? I tried (set SurfaceView to INVISIBLE and set converted byte[] as Bitmap into ImageView but there wasn't a result

Comment: "then how to put my bitmap in the imageView in the same Activity?" -- use `decodeByteArray()` on `BitmapFactory` to get a `Bitmap`, then call `setImageBitmap()` on the `ImageView`. Do not use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and do not use `setBackground()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did it, everything is the same, but I saw in logs "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3600x4800, max=4096x4096). Then I created ScaledBitmap of it (360x480), but I get the same message.

Comment: "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3600x4800, max=4096x4096)" -- use a `BitmapFactory.Options` with a suitable `inSampleSize` to downsample the image when you use `decodeByteArray()`. For example, try `inSampleSize` of 2.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did the same via BitmapFactory.Options (created bmOptions and passed it into decodeByteArray as the 4th parameter, my inSampleSize was 4) and message is the same for some reason. I have no idea why is it so.

Comment: @CommonsWare what can be the problem then?

Comment: Sorry, I am out of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with ContentProvider, it may sometimes prove useful though a bit of implementation need to be handled by yourself, but its not bad. Another thing you could do is put the Bitmap object in a queue or hashmap in a singleton class and pass the id of that bitmap by intent, the called activity will take the id and pull it from there. You need to handle some synchronizing there.